# How to fill image with percentage height?

Tags: html, css

I want to fill my image percentage using dynamic data. I'm looking for the best solution to this issue.
For now, my first idea is to set div absolute to relative image, and it almost works, but I don't know why my div with `.fill` class do not hide under image. I tried using few combinantions of `z-index`, but it didn't work.

Is my idea ok, or are the better solutions to do this?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightcoral;
}

.male {
  position: relative;
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/UqVu96f.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 37px;
  height: 157px;
}

.fill {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="male">
    <div class="fill" style="height: 45%;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you want to solve this with z-index you have to add `position: relative;z-index: 0;` to container then `z-index:-1` to the fill element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multiple background instead. You simply need to control the order of the layers to decide which one should be above the other:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightcoral;
}

.female {
  background: 
    url("https://i.imgur.com/qsVFCFh.png") center / cover,
    linear-gradient(lightblue,lightblue)   bottom / 100% var(--p,0),
    lightgray;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  width: 74px;
  height: 157px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="female" style="--p:45%;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! Will this solution (change CSS variable inline) work in react, in jsx syntax?

Comment: @sosick I don't know, you can try and see (I don't know react). If it's not working you can simply change the background-size `background-size:cover, 100% 42%`

Answer (score 2):

Taking the `.fill` outside of the `.female` will let you position it below it in the `DOM`.

Placing them both into a wrapper will let you position them inside that neatly and will stop the `.fill` overflowing.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightcoral;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 74px;
  height: 157px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.female {
  position: relative;
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/qsVFCFh.png");
  background-size: cover;
  width: 74px;
  height: 157px;
  z-index:2;
}

.fill {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="female"></div>
    <div class="fill" style="height: 45%;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```